# How to properly to render to texture with command buffer in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, shader, rendering, hlsl

Is there clear examples on how to perform a rendering to a texture properly in Unity 2020.3? The full code is hard to read but the basic idea is this.

```
// Here's what inside the RenderPipeline.Render()

// Draw to RT
mAlbedoID = Shader.PropertyToID("_RPDeferredShadingAlbedo")
mDepthID = Shader.PropertyToID("_RPDeferredShadingDepth"),

mCommandBuffer.GetTemporaryRT(mAlbedoID, 800, 450, 0, FilterMode.Bilinear, RenderTextureFormat.Default);
mCommandBuffer.GetTemporaryRT(mDepthID, 800, 450, 24, FilterMode.Bilinear, RenderTextureFormat.Depth);
mCommandBuffer.SetRenderTarget(mAlbedoID , mDepthID);
mCommandBuffer.ClearRenderTarget(true, true, Color.clear, 1);
deviceContext.DrawSkybox(mainCam);

// Draw to screen
mCommandBuffer.SetRenderTarget(BuiltinRenderTextureType.CameraTarget, RenderBufferLoadAction.DontCare, RenderBufferStoreAction.Store);
mCommandBuffer.DrawProcedural(Matrix4x4.identity, mPostProcessMaterial, (int)Pass.Copy, MeshTopology.Triangles, 6);
deviceContext.ExecuteCommandBuffer(buffer);
mCommandBuffer.Clear();
```

The shader code is just to simply sample the texture. No need to care about the vertex shader cuz i've tested it in some shader editors and it works.

```
Shader "Hidden/RPDeferredShading/PostFX" {
    Properties
    {
        _RPDeferredShadingAlbedo("_RPDeferredShadingAlbedo", 2D) = "black" {}
        _RPDeferredShadingNormal("_RPDeferredShadingNormal", 2D) = "black" {}
        _RPDeferredShadingDepth("_RPDeferredShadingDepth", 2D) = "black" {}
    }

        SubShader{
            Cull Off
            ZTest Always
            ZWrite Off

            HLSLINCLUDE
            //#include "../ShaderLibrary/HLSLUtils.hlsl"
            //#include "PostFX.hlsl"
            float4 _ProjectionParams;

            Texture2D _RPDeferredShadingAlbedo;
            Texture2D _RPDeferredShadingNormal;
            Texture2D _RPDeferredShadingDepth;

            SamplerState sampler_RPDeferredShadingAlbedo = sampler_state {
                Texture = <_RPDeferredShadingAlbedo>;
                MipFilter = LINEAR;
                MinFilter = LINEAR;
                MagFilter = LINEAR;
            };


            struct VSOutput {
                float4 positionCS : SV_POSITION;
                float2 screenUV : VAR_SCREEN_UV;
            };

            // Draw quad data
            VSOutput VSPostFX(uint vertexID : SV_VERTEXID) {
                VSOutput output;
                output.positionCS = float4(
                    vertexID <= 1 ? -1.0 : 3.0,
                    vertexID == 1 ? 3.0 : -1.0,
                    0.0, 1.0
                    );
                output.screenUV = float2(
                    vertexID <= 1 ? 0.0 : 2.0,
                    vertexID == 1 ? 2.0 : 0.0
                    );

                // Fix screen coord difference caused by APIs
                if (_ProjectionParams.x < 0.0) {
                    output.screenUV.y = 1.0 - output.screenUV.y;
                }
                return output;
            }

            float4 FSPostFX(VSOutput fin) : SV_TARGET{
                //return float4(fin.screenUV, 0.0, 1.0);
                float4 textureColor = _RPDeferredShadingAlbedo.Sample(sampler_RPDeferredShadingAlbedo, fin.screenUV);
                return textureColor;
            }
            ENDHLSL

            Pass {
                Name "Copy"

                HLSLPROGRAM
                    #pragma target 3.5
                    #pragma vertex VSPostFX
                    #pragma fragment FSPostFX
                ENDHLSL
            }
    }
}
```

With these code the skybox is drawn but idk where it's drawn to. But the texture is not correctly set in the `DrawProcedural()`. The debugger says the texture is UnityBlack
[image: UnityBlack when rendering frame buffer]
What am I missing exactly? I've tried doing this in d3d it should be all the steps.